# Wrong Mysql OUTFILE path in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm builing a PHP script that outputs a CSV from a Mysql table, but it saves the file everytime in `mysql/data/export.csv` path instead of the specified one. What am I doing wrong ? I'm using XAMPP local server.

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "master.php";

$export_path =  __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "export" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "export.csv";

$query = <<<SQL
SELECT op,cid,lac,rnc,lat,lng,ratio,data,rfu
FROM cells
INTO OUTFILE '?'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
SQL;

$statement = db()->prepare($query);
$statement->execute([$export_path]);

header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv";');
readfile($export_path);
```

P.S. if I remove the quotes from the question mark in `INTO OUTFILE '?'` it gives me this error:

> PDO::prepare(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '? FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY ' '' at line 3 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\celldb\export.php on line 14

Answer (score 0):

It isn't [clearly documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) but I suspect that the `SELECT... INTO OUTFILE` construct does not support bind parameters. That's why the place-holder shows up in the error message when you run the fixed code (passing a literal `'?'` string as in the original code has obviously no chance to work—in fact I'm surprised you get the right file name in the wrong directory).

It does work if you let PHP emulate prepared statements:

```
$pdo = new PDO(..., [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
]);
```

... because that way it's a client-side operation. But doing so in the middle of your project lifetime can break other things. A safer alternative would be to avoid prepared statements here:

```
$query = sprintf(<<<SQL
SELECT op,cid,lac,rnc,lat,lng,ratio,data,rfu
FROM cells
INTO OUTFILE '%s'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
SQL
, $db()->quote($export_path));
```

Comment: It is strange because `LOAD DATA INFILE` supports prepared statements